# Install Lubuntu on external HDD and UEFI Partitions!

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, external-hdd

I want to install Lubuntu from my bootable USB drive stick (where I use it in test mode) to an external HDD of 1 TB that I bought, while ignoring the laptop and its drives as they are full and without a working OS so I need to back up and save data.

I am NOT a regular Linux user, I don't even know commands and terminal use, but its working for what I want and the install didn't sound hard but I seem to be missing something. I found plenty of info, even here that helped and I followed, and there's a lot about UEFI/BIOS and Swap partitions and such, but it's time consuming to backtrack all of that to what I want with no basic awareness of linux commands (i.e. takes a long time and memory).

SO I was hoping for a more precise answer from where I am at now. Here's what I did so far, but basically I managed to install but my partitions are not visible in the Boot Screen, it just shows the Toshiba HDD as a whole.

This is how I set up my partitions with GParted, with the big chunk of the space wanting to keep it free for stuff. Now I did take the Swap space from the smaller 30 GB partition, idk if that is a problem.

[Partition Arrangement](http://oi57.tinypic.com/6s70pf.jpg)

And in the install screen I set up the space for Linux as Primary ext4 journaling system with mount point / and the Swap Space as Primary too. I tried the install both with it mounted and unmounted I believe, neither worked.

[Install Screen](http://oi58.tinypic.com/2ltaxl.jpg)

I also read something about a BIOS partition and I guess I need some terminal commands or other software to make my partitions visible on boot or something. I just don't know anything about dealing with UEFI, BIOS, DOS, GRUB or any of that, so I would appreciate some help here.